# Instead of 00, 01... in Karnaugh's map, \overline{B}\overline{C}, \overline{B}C... are needed

Tags: tables, labels, annotations, karnaugh

The MWE is given below:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{letter}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{karnaugh-map}

\begin{document}
\begin{karnaugh-map}[4][2][1][$BC$][$A$]
        \minterms{1,2,4,7}
        \maxterms{0,3,5,6}
        \implicant{1}{1}
        \implicant{2}{2}
        \implicant {4}{4}
        \implicant{7}{7}
    \end{karnaugh-map}
\end{document}
```

[image: The output is:]

I don't want `A` in the column side (with `0` and `1`), instead I want `\overline{A}` and `A` in place of `0` and `1` respectively. Similarly in the row side, I don't want `BC` (with `00`, `01`, `11`, `10`). Instead of `00` I want `\overline{B}\overline{C}`, instead of `01` I want `\overline{B}C`, instead of `11` I want `BC` and instead of `10` I want `B\overline{C}`.

Comment: Just for my understanding: Did you read its manual https://ctan.mirror.norbert-ruehl.de/graphics/pgf/contrib/karnaugh-map/karnaugh-map.pdf ? // Please remove packages not needed next time before posting. Thank you

Comment: Yes, I went through it. But was not able to get a solution.

Comment: Right, it doesn‘t seem to provide this option. Perhaps the best thing is to contact the author of this package. Alternatives: a) see topics related to this package on ctan, b) use a different approach, e.g. via tables, tikz etc., c) search this site, which provides many similar Q&As

Comment: I think, the package `tikz-karnaugh` provides more functionality which could help you (but I did not read the manual completely).

Comment: @JasperHabicht I've just checked that library, it's not going to be easy either (but fixable with a bit work). Even worse, it has no interface for what `\implicant` does. The author actually uses a separate software for that, see section 8 of the manual.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel Well, at first it looked as if is was a good idea, since it appeared to be highly customizable. But then, I realized that the `karnaugh-map` package is actually also quite customizable since it is also based on Ti*k*Z (as can be seen in my answer). To use external software just to place some 1s into a 2x4 matrix is indeed maybe a bit overkill ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hm, it is possible, but sadly only in a quite hacky way. The reason is that the zeros and ones are hard-coded in the code of the `karnaugh-map` package and therefore not easily editable.

What works is to first grab the hard coded node contents of the relevant cells and discard it into a box that is never used, then add the replacement text to the node contents. A small correction to the text height is needed. Note that due to the global `\tikzset`, the settings are also valid for other matrices that follow. If you don't want this, consider to scope everything using `\bgroup` and `\egroup` or the like.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{karnaugh-map}

\newsavebox{\gobblebox}

\begin{document}
\tikzset{
    text height=0.66em,
    row 1 column 2/.style={
        nodes={
            execute at begin node=$\overline{B}\overline{C}$\begin{lrbox}{\gobblebox},
            execute at end node=\end{lrbox},
        }
    },
    row 1 column 3/.style={
        nodes={
            execute at begin node=$\overline{B}C$\begin{lrbox}{\gobblebox},
            execute at end node=\end{lrbox},
        }
    },
    row 1 column 4/.style={
        nodes={
            execute at begin node=$BC$\begin{lrbox}{\gobblebox},
            execute at end node=\end{lrbox},
        }
    },
    row 1 column 5/.style={
        nodes={
            execute at begin node=$B\overline{C}$\begin{lrbox}{\gobblebox},
            execute at end node=\end{lrbox},
        }
    },
    row 2 column 1/.style={
        nodes={
            execute at begin node=$\overline{A}$\begin{lrbox}{\gobblebox},
            execute at end node=\end{lrbox},
        }
    },
    row 3 column 1/.style={
        nodes={
            execute at begin node=$A$\begin{lrbox}{\gobblebox},
            execute at end node=\end{lrbox},
        }
    },
}
\begin{karnaugh-map}[4][2][1][][]
    \minterms{1,2,4,7}
    \maxterms{0,3,5,6}
    \implicant{1}{1}
    \implicant{2}{2}
    \implicant{4}{4}
    \implicant{7}{7}
\end{karnaugh-map}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Looks like `karnaugh-map` really does not provide an easy way to modify this behavior. You could use `\patchcmd` from `etoolbox` I guess but the relevant commands are bulky. You could copy `karnaugh-map.sty` to your local directory and modify the source there.

Save the text below as `patch_file`:

```
--- a/karnaugh-map.sty  2023-07-20 07:48:03.000000000 -0400
+++ b/karnaugh-map.sty  2023-08-07 08:40:40.505867916 -0400
@@ -253,8 +253,8 @@
         \IfValueT{#1}{\renewcommand{\@karnaughmap@var@labelA@}{#1}}%
         \IfValueT{#2}{\renewcommand{\@karnaughmap@var@labelB@}{#2}}%
         \IfValueT{#3}{\renewcommand{\@karnaughmap@var@labelC@}{#3}}%
-        \renewcommand{\@karnaughmap@var@labelX@}{\@karnaughmap@var@labelB@\@karnaughmap@var@labelA@}%
-        \renewcommand{\@karnaughmap@var@labelY@}{\@karnaughmap@var@labelC@}%
+        \renewcommand{\@karnaughmap@var@labelX@}{}%
+        \renewcommand{\@karnaughmap@var@labelY@}{}%
         \renewcommand{\@karnaughmap@var@labeltype@}{2}%
       \fi
     \fi
@@ -353,10 +353,14 @@
     \fi
     \ifnum\@karnaughmap@var@mapsizex@\@karnaughmap@var@mapsizey@\@karnaughmap@var@mapsizez@=421
       \renewcommand{\@karnaughmap@local@matrixtemplate@}{%
-                     \&                      00 \&                      01 \&                      11 \&                      10 \& \phantom{00} \\
-                  0  \& |(000000)|  \phantom{0} \& |(000001)|  \phantom{0} \& |(000011)|  \phantom{0} \& |(000010)|  \phantom{0} \&              \\
-                  1  \& |(000100)|  \phantom{0} \& |(000101)|  \phantom{0} \& |(000111)|  \phantom{0} \& |(000110)|  \phantom{0} \&              \\
-        \phantom{00} \&                         \&                         \&                         \&                         \&              \\
+        \& $\overline{\mbox{\@karnaughmap@var@labelB@}}\overline{\mbox{\@karnaughmap@var@labelC@}}$%
+        \& $\overline{\mbox{\@karnaughmap@var@labelB@}}$\@karnaughmap@var@labelC@%
+        \& \@karnaughmap@var@labelB@$\overline{\mbox{\@karnaughmap@var@labelC@}}$%
+        \& \@karnaughmap@var@labelB@\@karnaughmap@var@labelC@%
+        \& \phantom{00} \\
+        $\overline{\mbox{\@karnaughmap@var@labelA@}}$  \& |(000000)|  \phantom{0} \& |(000001)|  \phantom{0} \& |(000011)|  \phantom{0} \& |(000010)|  \phantom{0} \&              \\
+        \@karnaughmap@var@labelA@                      \& |(000100)|  \phantom{0} \& |(000101)|  \phantom{0} \& |(000111)|  \phantom{0} \& |(000110)|  \phantom{0} \&              \\
+                                          \phantom{00} \&                         \&                         \&                         \&                         \&              \\
       }%
     \fi
     \ifnum\@karnaughmap@var@mapsizex@\@karnaughmap@var@mapsizey@\@karnaughmap@var@mapsizez@=441
```

Then do:

```
cp $(kpsewhich karnaugh-map.sty) . && patch -p1 < patch_file
```

```latex
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{karnaugh-map}

\begin{document}
\begin{karnaugh-map}[4][2][1]
  \minterms{1,2,4,7}
  \maxterms{0,3,5,6}
  \implicant{1}{1}
  \implicant{2}{2}
  \implicant{4}{4}
  \implicant{7}{7}
\end{karnaugh-map}
\begin{karnaugh-map}[4][2][1][$A$][$B$][$C$]
  \minterms{1,2,4,7}
  \maxterms{0,3,5,6}
  \implicant{1}{1}
  \implicant{2}{2}
  \implicant{4}{4}
  \implicant{7}{7}
\end{karnaugh-map}
\end{document}
```

There are other "templates" for 2x2 or 4x4 you will have to modify, but you can get the idea from what I did above.

[image]

Comment: I ordered the top labels wrong, but you get the idea